# CData unmarshalling with JAXB over xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, sax

I'm trying to convert a third party xml using an xsl transformation and then converting the resultant xml to a java object with JAXB. 
But some where in between an element content marked as CDATA gets lost.

Here is my sample thirdparty xml

```
<person>
   <name>aName</name>
</person>
```

XSL transformation

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <User>
        <personName><xsl:value-of select="//name"/></personName>
        <!-- Saving input xml as CDATA for future ref -->
        <inputXml>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </inputXml>     
    </User>
</xsl:template>
```

Java Class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User{
    @XmlElement
    public String personName;
    @XmlElement
    public String inputXml
}
```

Translation

```
    JAXBResult jaxbResult = new JAXBResult(JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class));
    newXslTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(thirdPatyXmlFile), jaxbOutput);
    User user = (User)jaxbResult.getResult();
    System.out.println(user.inputXml);
```

But the above code outputs the inputXml as **]]>**.
I'm able to get the inputXml if I hard-coded the CDATA as below, but not when I generate it dynamically.

```
<inputXml><![CDATA[<person><name>aName</name></person>]]></inputXml>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JAXBResult` is a `SAXResult` therefore the transformation result is issued as series of SAX events and a JAXB unmarshaller uses them to construct your `User` object.

This is an effective technique to avoid writing the transformation and reparsing later when you unmarshal.

Unfortunately your CDATA hack does not go well with this.
Within `<inputXml>` the ContentHandler of the JAXBResult sees text `"<![CDATA["`, then your whole input document as a series of element and text events, then the closing text event `"]]>"` - and the last one is used as value for `User.inputXml`.

Seems that you need to transform to a memory buffer and then unmarshal from that.

Comment: I've worked out with the 2 step approach. Was looking for any other effective solution. Thanks for the explanation.